# Create intermediates dates for several factors with not equal start/end dates

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

```
# My data set
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
DS_F_norm_sel<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/indexes_dates_bug.csv")
DS_F_norm_sel <- DS_F_norm_raw%>%dplyr::select(STAND,DATE,STATUS,SAVI_MAX,MSR_SD,GCI_SD)
DS_F_norm_sel$DATE <- lubridate::ymd(DS_F_norm_sel$DATE)
max_min_stands<-DS_F_norm_sel%>%group_by(STAND)%>%dplyr::summarize(max_date=max(DATE),min_date=min(DATE))
as.data.frame(max_min_stands)
#                     STAND   max_date   min_date
# 1            ALAMEDA_007A 2022-03-28 2022-02-11
# 2             ALCINA_001A 2022-04-20 2022-02-09
# 3           ALDOSANI_031A 2022-06-11 2022-02-11
# ...
# 184        VILAPALMA_033K 2022-04-02 2022-02-01
# 185        VILAPALMA_038G 2022-05-22 2022-02-01
```

But now, I'd like to create a new data frame (`new.DS_F_norm_sel`) with the same structure as the original one, but with the dates between the min and max dates for each stand by week.
My desired data frame should look like this:

```
new.DS_F_norm_sel
STAND   DATE
ALAMEDA_007A 2022-02-11
ALAMEDA_007A 2022-02-18
ALAMEDA_007A 2022-02-25
...
ALAMEDA_007A 2022-03-28
...

VILAPALMA_038G 2022-02-01
VILAPALMA_038G 2022-02-08
...
VILAPALMA_038G 2022-05-22
```

I've tried to do it with using `dplyr`, but it doesn't work. Please, could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about the two different goals, one is to create the series, the other is to add a location for each series.

I used a loop to create a series for each location then stack the using row binding them.

```
#create empty dataframe
df<-data.frame()
# use loop to iterate through your locations
for (loc in c(
  "ALAMEDA_007A",
  "VILAPALMA_038G")){
#create a dataframe with series of dates for each location
temp<- data.frame(location=  loc,
                dates=seq(as.Date("2022/02/22"), by = "day", length.out = 50))
#stack the temporary data frame on your final dataframe
df<- rbind(temp, df)}
```

The key is setting the right number of days out to `length.out=?`

[image]